# TensorFlow - Fashion MNIST Steps Per Epoch

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm working with the Kera's Fashion MNIST dataset. When I fit my model, I noticed to complete one epoch it would have to go through 1500 steps.

```
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=30, validation_split=0.2)

Epoch 3/30
1500/1500 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.4494 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8438 - val_loss: 0.4691 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8308
Epoch 4/30
964/1500 [==================>...........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4294 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8504
```

I was looking at the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) for the fit function, but couldn't understand why the default steps were set to 1500. I understand when the `steps_per_epoch` is `None` the behavior is dependent on the data type of the dataset, but how can I check if the data type is a tensor or tf.data?

Comment: The number of steps per epoch is equal to `ceil(samples / batch_size)`. It does not depend on the data type.

Comment: @jakub, if I don't specify the ```batch_size``` in my code where is it getting defaulted in?

Comment: The default batch size is 32. That's in the `model.fit` documentation.

Comment: @jakub, that what doesn't make sense to me. If steps per epoch equal ```ceil(60000/32)```, the log output should be 1875/1875, right?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of steps per epoch is equal to `ceil(samples / batch_size)`. The default batch size in `model.fit` is 32 ([documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)). If the MNIST training data has 60000 samples, then each epoch would take 60000 / 32 = 1875 steps.

`model.fit` also supports splitting your data into training and validation sets. You have done this with `validation_split=0.2`, so only 80% of the samples are part of the training set (20% are for validation). The new calculation would be 0.8 * 60000 / 32 = 1500. This is why you see 1500 steps per epoch.

Comment: I just discovered this and was about to answer my own question.